# How to require gdb to save both user input and its output to the same file?

Tags: gdb

I know that I can

1. ask `gdb` to save my command history to a file, say `gdb.history`, by `set history filename gdb.history` and `set history save on`, and
2. ask it to log its output to another file, say `gdb.output`, by `set logging file gdb.output` and `set logging on`.

But how to require `gdb` to save both my command line inputs and its responding outputs to the same file, in the order of they occur in that GDB session?

I tried using the same file name in both history and logging command, it does not work, contents of that file will be overwrite by GDB command history when I quit from `gdb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try playing with logging plus "set trace-commands on".  I don't know whether that will do what you want though.  There's a bug open for this functionality: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7219.  I see I commented on it but I don't remember anything about it any more :)